# The best error term for the second moment

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-number-theorem

Let $r_2(n)$ be the number of representations of a positive integer $n$ as a sum of two prime squares, i.e. $n=p^2+q^2$. Consider $S_1(x)= \sum_{n \le x} r_2(n)$ and $S_2(x) = \sum_{n \le x}r_2^2(n)$. 
For the first one by the prime number theorem we have
$$S_1(x) = \frac{\pi x}{\log^2 x}+O\left(\frac{x \log \log x}{\log^3 x} \right).$$
In [here](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=1968&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=pubyear&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=rieger&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=All&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq)

Rieger proved that $$S_2(x) = 2 \sum_{n \le x}r_2(n)+O\left(\frac{x}{\log^3 x} \right).$$
(this result improves in the error term on Erdos.)

Is there anything better known/provable about the error terms in the above formulas?

Comment: Just as in the prime number theorem, where we can't get a better error term than $\pi(x) = x/\log x + O(x/\log^2x)$ unless we change to the more complicated main term $\int^x dt/\log t$, I'm guessing that there's no essentially better error term for $S_1(x)$ unless one uses a more complicated main term.

Comment: In the PNT we can have $O(x\exp(-c\sqrt{\log x}))$ by Landau zero-free region and something slightly better by Vinogradov-Korobov. But can we get Landau type of error term in $S_1$ and $S_2$? (I am fine with using $\text{li}(x)$ in the main term).

Comment: Since $S_1(x) = \sum_{p\le\sqrt x} \pi(\sqrt{x-p^2})$, I would use the prime number theorem in each term, write the resulting main-term sum as a Riemann–Stieltjes integral, integrate by parts, and so on. That will give you a more complicated main term with a better error term.